# How do I show that the product of even and odd number is always congruent to 2 modulo 4?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Here is what I have and I think I am really close.

$(2k + 1) * 2l$ = $4kl + 2l$

**EDIT**

My question is stupidly wrong, I probably meant to ask the product of odd number and even number not divisible by 4.

Comment: $$4k^2+2k\equiv2k\pmod4$$ Now what if $k$ is odd, and is even?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true.  $3\cdot 4=12 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$

Comment: I probably wanted to ask the product of odd and even number not divisible by 4.

Comment: Two consecutive even numbers are of the form 4k or 4k + 2. So, if it is not 4k then it has to be 4k + 2.

Comment: That is asking the same thing.  What you can say is the product of an odd number and one of the form $2 \bmod 4$ is $2 \bmod 4$